# Añadir PrimaryKey generada por Trigger a tabla relacionada

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger, insert

La cuestión es que tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
/*Estructura de la tabla pedidos */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pedidos;
CREATE TABLE pedidos (
  numeroPedido int(11),
  fechaPedido date NOT NULL,
  fechaEnvío date DEFAULT NULL,
  estado varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  comentarios text,
  IdCliente int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (numeroPedido),
  KEY IdCliente (IdCliente),
  CONSTRAINT orders_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (IdCliente) REFERENCES clientes (IdCliente)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


/*Estructura de la tabla productos */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS productos;
CREATE TABLE productos (
  codigoProducto varchar(15),
  nombreProducto varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  lineaProducto varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  descripcionProducto text NOT NULL,
  cantidadStock smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  precioCompra decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (codigoProducto),
  KEY lineaProducto (lineaProducto),
  CONSTRAINT products_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (lineaProducto) REFERENCES lineasProducto (lineaProducto)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Estructura de la tabla detallesPedido */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS detallesPedido;
CREATE TABLE detallesPedido (
  numeroPedido int(11),
  codigoProducto varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  cantidadPedida int(11) NOT NULL,
  precioUnidad decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (numeroPedido,codigoProducto),
  KEY codigoProducto (codigoProducto),
  CONSTRAINT orderdetails_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (numeroPedido) REFERENCES pedidos (numeroPedido),
  CONSTRAINT orderdetails_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (codigoProducto) REFERENCES productos (codigoProducto)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Y quiero generar mediante Triggers las PK de cada una de ellas. Lo estoy haciendo así:

```
/*TRIGGERS*/
delimiter $ 
CREATE TRIGGER numero_Pedido BEFORE INSERT ON pedidos FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE numero_Pedido int;
        SET numero_Pedido = (SELECT ifnull(max(numeroPedido), 0) FROM pedidos) +1;
        SET new.numeroPedido=numero_Pedido;
end $

delimiter $ 
CREATE TRIGGER codigo_productos BEFORE INSERT ON productos FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE codigo_producto int;
        SET codigo_producto = (SELECT ifnull(max(convert(substring(codigoProducto,3), signed integer)), 0) FROM productos) +1;
        SET new.codigoProducto=CONCAT('P-',LPAD(codigo_producto,3,'0'));        
end $
```

El caso es que luego, al hacer las inserciones, no sé cómo añadir esas PK de las tablas de pedidos y productos que he generado con triggers en la tabla de detallesPedido, para que sea automático.

Las inserciones en pedidos y productos las tengo así, y la PK de cada una se genera automáticamente con el trigger:

```
/*Datos de la tabla pedidos */
insert into pedidos(fechaPedido,fechaEnvío,estado,comentarios,IdCliente) values 
('2003-01-06','2003-01-10','Shipped',NULL,103);

/*Datos de la tabla productos */
insert into productos(nombreProducto,lineaProducto,descripcionProducto,cantidadStock,precioCompra) values 
('Camiseta básica','Camisetas','Care for water: producido utilizando menos agua. Etiquetamos bajo el nombre Join Life las prendas que se producen utilizando tecnologías y materias primas que nos ayudan a reducir el impacto medioambiental de nuestros productos. ',540,'33.30'),
('Pantalón pliegues','Pantalones','Pantalón de tiro alto con cintura deconstruida. Bolsillos laterales y falsos bolsillos de vivo y con solapa en espalda.',6553,'43.26');
```

La idea es que al hacer esta inserción se añadan automáticamente a la tabla los PK (FK para esta tabla) antes generadas:

```
/*Datos de la tabla detallesPedido */
insert  into detallesPedido(cantidadPedida,precioUnidad) values 
(50,'55.09'),
(22,'75.46');
```

Gracias!

Comment: eso a lo mejor con alter table te funciona te dejo el manual : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

Comment: ¿Cómo es posible que insertes detalles de pedido sin especificar a qué pedido pertenecen esos detalles?

Comment: @DavidJP Se supone que en la base las inserciones de pedidos y productos ya están hechas y se ha generado una PK en cada tabla que es la que quiero que se añada con un trigger en detallesPedido.

Comment: @Serzox una pregunta al hacer una inserción sobre que tabla

Comment: @Serzox Aunque ya tengas los pedidos y productos, en `detallesPedido`, vuelve a ser necesario especificar a qué pedido pertenece ese detalle y qué producto trata, son precisamente tus dos claves ajenas. Observa el diseño de tus tablas y lo verás

Comment: @DavidJP Hola, David! Con el trigger genero las PK automáticamente en las tablas de pedidos y productos (he añadido ese código para que se vea). La duda es esa, cómo agrego cada una de esas PK generadas a la tabla de detallesPedido. Supongo que es con otro trigger, pero no me sale.

Comment: @Serzox Es lo que estoy tratando de explicarte: imagínate que tienes una tabla de clientes y otra de facturas, aunque generes los ID de cliente de forma automática, no existe la forma de que un sistema ADIVINE a qué cliente corresponde una factura que acabas de insertar, a no ser que tú, como usuario, se lo especifiques. Hay datos que se pueden calcular, pero éste tienes que facilitarlo, no hay forma de calcularlo, a no ser que únicamente tengas un único cliente, cada cliente tenga una fecha asignada de compra o exista algún criterio similar. Pues, con tu tabla, te pasa lo mismo

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, David! Entiendo entonces que eso tendría que hacerlo de forma manual, no hay una manera automática por así decirlo de establecer eso a través de la BBDD, no? Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @Serzox Exacto, eso es. De una base de datos nunca podrás obtener información si no has guardado previamente los datos necesarios para obtenerla. De lo contrario, tendrías un bola de cristal, no un SGBD :D

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @DavidJP. Y es que esto no es para resolverlo por medio de TRIGGER. Imagina una tienda cualquiera, en su web tú tienes unos productos, los cuales seleccionas (desde una lista desplegable, un panel o lo que sea) para crear un pedido. No se adivina nada ahí, tú seleccionas los productos que quieres, el sistema recoge los ID de esos productos seleccionados y crea el pedido. Para esto  un TRIGGER no aplica. Para lo que sí aplicaría un TRIGGER sería por ejemplo para controlar el inventario, descontando esos productos que fueron seleccionados si la compra se confirma.